# Воспроизведение .webp на android xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, webp

Есть ли способ воспроизвести .webp в xamarin?

Comment: То есть воспроизвести гугло-формат графического файла в приложении, написанном под гугло-операционку...ну даже не знаю.

Comment: @aepot попробуй, если получится - напиши, буду рад

Comment: после первых 30 секунд поиска в гугле https://github.com/luberda-molinet/WebP.Touch

Comment: А так, я думаю WebView точно может показывать такие картинки.

Comment: это для ios и mac

Comment: А это? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6e286c8b-4ff2-4b3c-a8c0-0835117bb7e8/does-xamarindroid-supports-webp-?forum=xamarinandroid

Comment: @aepot мне бы не хотелось использовать webview

Comment: @aepot это для amarin.droid(not xamarin.forms)

Comment: Вот еще что нашел https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/3575, или это опять не то?